# Could I be sued for a similar-sounding domain name?

Tags: trademark

I'm a software/web dev, and I had an idea for a joke website.  Since all of the variations with the word "news" I would like are taken, I thought I'd just replace it with "shoes."

A few things worth noting:

- I'm in the US.
- It is *not* a parody of an existing website and does not defame
  anybody.
- I did a quick search of the trademark database, and it doesn't seem
  to infringe any trademarks.
- I would put a small Google ads banner towards the top of the page, so
  it's possible that I could make a profit from it.
- But the url *is* still similar to another website's, simply with the
  name "news" replaced by "shoes."  This website is currently occupied
  by a cybersquatter.
- There's another url that it's kinda/sorta similar to, which is also
  occupied by a cybersquatter.

Is this something that I could be sued for?

Comment: Wait, so is there an actual website operating under that name or is it *merely* the fact that the domain is registered? I'm not sure trademark would even apply to a cybersquatter. Trademark is meant to prevent brand confusion, but that's not possible if all they own is a domain because *there is no brand to confuse it with*. They're not providing anything on the domain, just holding it.

Comment: It's *just* registered.  There's nothing actually there except the "You can buy this domain" stuff.